# django manytomany model linked to 'self' makes a link to both objects when selected. i would like only a one way link

Tags: django

I'm using a manytomany object in my model which is linked to 'self'. The reason for this is because i need to be able to select other objects from within the same class model. However my problem is this:

If object A has object B selected within the manytomany field. If you go to edit object B, then A is also selected. The way i would like it to work is, if object B is selected from within object A then i do not want object A selected within object B.

A linked to B, B **not** linked to A

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: > If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with self, set symmetrical to False.
[ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with self,set symmetrical to False

See [ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)